# Creating table view with user profile2

Tags: views, theming, users

I installed profile2 and i created two different profile types. I used views module to create a table of some fields of user profile types. Now i want to create a link in table to see user whole profile fields in page. I don't know what is the user profile2 link? I also could not see users profile2 field by administrator user.

Answer (score 1):

In the View create a *relationship* with the *User uid*. After this You should see a few more field options for you to use.

[image]
[image]